# Steam API объект (цифры в JSON)

Tags: javascript

```
{
  '438640': {
    success: true,
    data: {
      type: 'game',
      name: 'LEGO® STAR WARS™: The Force Awakens',
      steam_appid: 438640,
      required_age: 0,
      is_free: false,
      controller_support: 'full',
      dlc: [Array],
```

У меня есть объект, полученный из ссылки https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=438640&cc=tw, как мне обратиться к объекту 438640 (что нужно написать вместо [APP ID])?

```
https.get('https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=438640&cc=tw', (resp) => {
  let data = '';
  let appInfo = '';

  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    appInfo = JSON.parse(data).explanation;
    appInfo = appInfo.[APP ID];
    console.log(appInfo);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: `appInfo = JSON.parse(data)[438640];`